# jQuery UI get specific digit from ui.value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to get only the 2nd from last digit from the ui.value on a slider.

Here is how I can get the last digit:

```
var $lastNumber = ui.value % 10;
```

This is the actual code I am working with:

```
activeBackground_2 = 'url(images/numbers/20'+ui.value % 10+'.png)';
```

How would I get the 2nd from last digit ONLY? Not everything after the 2nd digit, rather only that specific digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
var $lastNumber = parseInt((ui.value / 10), 10) % 10;
```

Comment: Close but this is adding the last digit to the end of the ui.value as a percentage. eg: 1.6 When I really just need the 1 without the .6

Comment: I've edited my answer to include parseInt() which should fix that.

Comment: That breaks it. I edited my initial example to show my actual code. Will parseInt() work with jQuery code?

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed a paren. parseInt is native javascript, it'll work with anything provided when I type it into an answer I'm not wearing my fat fingers. Fixed now... again.